# Python: Generating list of numbers 1-10, but 1 ends up at the end of the list?

Tags: python, list

I have just started learning how to program using Python, and have been going through some exercises to help me improve. For one of the exercises, I have to program a Sieve of Eratosthenes, and as part of doing this, I wanted to generate a list of numbers 1 through *n*.

My code is as follows:

```
def primelist(n): #returns a list of all primes lower than or equal to n
    grid=[]
    k=1
    while k in range (1, n+1):
        grid.insert(-1, k)
        k+=1
    return grid
```

This is as far as I got, because when I tested what I had written so far with:

```
print(primelist(10))
```

my code output the list [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1] and I can't figure out why it is doing this. Any explanation would be much appreciated!

Comment: Adding the `python` tag to your question will make it easier for you to get a quick answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why it's backwards, but your code is not the way to add elements to a list. Also you don't use the variable `n` in your code (probably a typo), so I will just add the function to generate a list through 1 to `n`.

```
def primelist(n):
    grid=[]
    for k in range(1,n+1):
        grid.append(k)
    return grid
```

This code will return `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]` as you requested.

Comment: Yes, that was a typo, sorry. Thank you, that makes a lot more sense!

Comment: @leob after trying it, you can accept it as correct answer, which beneficial both for you and me.

Answer (score 3):

In Python, `list.insert(index, item)`
actually inserts `item` BEFORE `index`.

So `list.insert(-1, k)`inserts `k` before -1. Hence your results.

To do what you want to do properly, the following two lines are equivalent

```
list.insert(len(list), k)
list.append(k)
```

Both methods modify the actual list (instead of returning a new list), as expected.

See more here: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2010-January/073754.html

Answer (score 1):

`insert` method for list inserts the element at the index before the first argument. `-1` is the index of last element. So, when you are inserting at `-1`, you are always inserting just before the last element. For example you have a list `a` as:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
print a[-1]  # It will print 4
```

So, when you are trying to insert first element (1) in your list using `grid.insert(-1, k)`, it goes to last (or first as it will be only element), as there is no other element. All insert operations after first element add the elements to the second last position in the list.

This leads you see only `1` at last position while all other elements are in order as you expect.

As already mentioned by @coln, you can either use `list.append(k)` or `list.insert(len(list), k)` to insert/append/add elements to the end of the list.

Comment: Thank you, that explains the issue well. If that is how the insert operation works, does that mean you can't ever use that operation to insert an element in the final position of a list? Is the simplest way to instead accomplish this simply to splice lists together? ie to say: [1, 2, 3, 4]+[5] to get [1, 2, 3, 4,  5] and thus 'insert' the element 2 into the end of the list?

Comment: Glad it helped. To insert the element at last, you can user `list.insert(len(list), element)`. For your example, it will be `a = [1,2,3,4]` and then `a.insert(len(a), 5)`. Or simply `a.append(5)` would have done the same job.

Answer (score 0):

xrange can do this for you, remember to give xrange a end value that is one more than the one you want.

So to generate numbers from 1 to n : xrange(1,n+1)

The example below will give you a list from 1 to 10.

```
>>> primelist=list(xrange(1,11))
>>> primelist
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```